# Java TypesafeConfig generate config key and read its value

Tags: java, typesafe-config

I am using Typesafeconfig in my project. I want to read the config and generates a value, which is again a config key and I want to read this config key's value.

Example:

```
fs {
  city = ${CITY}
  number = ${NUMBER}
  cityNumberKey = ${CITY}"_"${NUMBER}
  cityNumber = ${fs.cityNumberKey}
}
```

In above example, the value of cityNumber is same as cityNumberKey. What I am actually trying to do is to read the value of cityNumberKey config.

Example, let's say if `city` is `Delhi` and `Number` is `31`, then I want to read the value of config `Delhi_31` in `cityNumber` object.

Appreciate any example for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

**reference.conf**

```
fs {
    city = "Delhi"
    number = 31
}
```

**myconf.conf**

```
conf {
    city = ${fs.city}
    number = ${fs.number}
    cityNumberKey = ${conf.city}"_"${conf.number}
    cityNumber = ${conf.cityNumberKey}
}
```

**TypesafeConfigTest.java**

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

public class TypesafeConfigTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Config refConfig = ConfigFactory.parseResources("reference.conf").resolve();
        Config myConfConfig = ConfigFactory.parseResources("myconf.conf").withFallback(refConfig).resolve();
        System.out.println("name: " + refConfig.getString("fs.city"));
        System.out.println("title: " + refConfig.getString("fs.number"));
        System.out.println("cityNumberKey: " + myConfConfig.getString("conf.cityNumberKey"));
        System.out.println("cityNumber: " + myConfConfig.getString("conf.cityNumber"));
    }
}
```

**Edit 1 :**

Using single configuration,

```
conf {
    city = "Delhi"
    number = 31
    cityNumberKey = ${conf.city}"_"${conf.number}
    cityNumber = ${conf.cityNumberKey}
}
```

**TypesafeConfigExamples.java**

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

public class TypesafeConfigExamples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Config refConfig = ConfigFactory.parseResources("myconf.conf").resolve();
        System.out.println("name: " + refConfig.getString("conf.city"));
        System.out.println("title: " + refConfig.getString("conf.number"));
        System.out.println("cityNumberKey: " + refConfig.getString("conf.cityNumberKey"));
        System.out.println("cityNumber: " + refConfig.getString("conf.cityNumber"));
    }
}
```